# Determining if a function is one-to-one or onto.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

We have two sets: $\{1,2\}$ and $\{a,b,c\}$. How would I go about listing the functions between these two sets and then identifying if those functions are either one-to-one or onto? Would the functions be $(1,a)(2,a)$etc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct the possible functions $f: \left\{ 1,2 \right\}\rightarrow \left\{ a,b,c \right\}$(check the definition of a function)

> $$ \left\{ (1,a), (2,b) \right\}, \left\{ (1,a), (2,c) \right\}, \,\dots$$

and then check if there are one to one, onto